# Date format is not recognized Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

view in snowflake as follows;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW A  AS(


SELECT tab1.colA,
       tab1.colB,
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(DATE_ACT_CREATED,'missing')='missing' THEN DATE ('1970-01- 01') ELSE TO_DATE(DATE_ACT_CREATED) END AS ACT_CREATED_DATE
    FROM tab1);
```

Please note that because of some reasons, column `DATE_ACT_CREATED` was defined as varchar earlier. This view is created fine. But when I try to retrieve records from it;

```
SELECT * FROM viewA;
```

I get following error,

```
Date '' is not recognized
```

But when I take out the entry;            `CASE WHEN COALESCE(DATE_ACT_CREATED,'missing')='missing' THEN DATE ('1970-01- 01') ELSE TO_DATE(DATE_ACT_CREATED) END AS ACT_CREATED_DATE` the error is gone.

May I know how can I handle this date error issue? Found this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500909/date-is-not-recognized-snowflake), but it couldn't help much.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because the case when DATE_ACT_CREATED is an empty string is not handled in your CASE condition. So the **TO_DATE** function couldn't work.

You should try [TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html). If your entry couldn't be casted as a date then it returns null that will be handled with your COALESCE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE viewA  AS(
SELECT 
       tab1.colA,
       tab1.colB,
       COALESCE(TRY_TO_DATE(DATE_ACT_CREATED), DATE('1970-01- 01')) AS ACT_CREATED_DATE
    FROM tab1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following query you will not get the error if the input is ''(Empty string), actual date, NULL keyword, or missing keyword.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW A
AS
SELECT COL1, COL2, 
      CASE WHEN COALESCE(DATE_AT_CREATED, '') = '' THEN DATE('1970-01-02') 
        ELSE CASE WHEN DATE_AT_CREATED = 'missing' THEN DATE('1970-01-02') ELSE TO_DATE(DATE_AT_CREATED) END
      END AS ACT_CREATED_DATE 
FROM TAB1;

SELECT * FROM A;
```